# Random Number add up to a defined number using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Hello PowerShell Experts,

I am working on a simple code that produces a list of product and task (A product has several task) with the time spend on it "Randomly". I want the totalTime add up the time to 40 (integer) (and can be changed as user defined e.g. 50 , 60, etc).

The code is working fine, but it just does not add up to 40. Can you please help ?

**Bonus:** Can I assign weight to a product or task, so that it gets a priority when the random selection happens ? e.g. I want to have more time spend on P3 and P7 with T3, T12 and T15. The time still should add up to 40.

```
cls
[int]$totalTime = 40 # This will be the number that the TotalTime Adds up

$taskCategories = @("T1"
"T2",
"T3",
"T4",
"T5",
"T6",
"T7",
"T8",
"T9",
"T10",
"T11",
"T12",
"T13",
"T14",
"T15")

$products = @("P1"
, "P2"
, "P3"
, "p4"
, "P5"
, "P6"
, "P7"
, "P8"
, "P9"
, "P10")

for ($i = 0; $i -le 1; ++$i)
{
    $totalTime = 0
    while ($totalTime -lt 40)
    {
        [int]$task = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 16
        [int]$product = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 11
        $time = Get-Random -Minimum 4 -Maximum 10

        Write-Output "$($products[$product])`t$($taskCategories[$task])`t$time"
        $totalTime = $totalTime + $time
    }
}
```

Below is the output that I am getting :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cls
[int]$totalTime = 40 # This will be the number that the TotalTime Adds up

$taskCategories = @("T1", "T2", "T3", "T4", "T5", 
                    "T6", "T7", "T8", "T9", "T10", "T11", "T12", "T13", "T14", "T15")

$products = @("P1", "P2", "P3", "P4", "P5", "P6", "P7", "P8", "P9", "P10")

$totalTime = 0
$MinValue = 4

for ($i = 0; $i -le 1; ++$i)
{

    while ($totalTime -lt 40)
    {
        if (40 - $totalTime -ge 10)
        {
        $MaxValue = 10
        }
        else 
        {
        $MaxValue = 40 - $totalTime
        }

        if ($MinValue -lt $MaxValue)
        {
        $MinValue = 4
        }
        else
        {
        $MinValue = $MaxValue
        }


        [int]$task = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 15
        [int]$product = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 10
        if ($MinValue -eq 4)
        {
        $time = Get-Random -Minimum $MinValue -Maximum $MaxValue
        }
        else
        {
        $time = $MaxValue
        }
        $totalTime = $totalTime + $time
        $Remainder = 40 - $totalTime
        if ($Remainder -le 3)
        {
        $time = $time + $Remainder
        $totalTime = $totalTime + $time
        }

        Write-Output "$($products[$product])`t$($taskCategories[$task])`t$time"

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move `$totalTime` out of the FOR LOOP which will work..

```
#######
$totalTime = 0
#######

for ($i = 0; $i -le 1; ++$i)
{
    while ($totalTime -lt 40)
    {
        [int]$task = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 16
        [int]$product = Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 11
        $time = Get-Random -Minimum 4 -Maximum 10

        Write-Output "$($products[$product])`t$($taskCategories[$task])`t$time"
        $totalTime = $totalTime + $time
    }
}
```

Comment: Silly me .. I should have thought about it. But even if I put the `$totalTime` as per your suggestion, the time is a bit over 40. Thanks for your help.